# Django and writing queries with lots of joins

Tags: django, django-models

I have trouble to make these kind of queries with lots of joins. I didn't found examples, but I guess they are not so complicated to write. It's just there are several FKs.

Here is the models.py (not complicated)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin): # Django custom user model
    # Some stuff

class CliProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class BizProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Card(models.Model):
    linked_client = models.ForeignKey(CliProfile, blank=True, null=True)

class Points(models.Model):
    benef_card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    at_owner = models.ForeignKey(BizProfile)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Quick description of the model**

- a user can be a client (using CliProfile) or a business (using BizProfile)
- each card is linked to a client
- each card contains a [points - business] association

This way: a client has a card and can has 3 points at Pizza Hut, and 5 points at McDonalds with the same card)

**The request I'm trying to write**

Functionally speaking, the purpose is a owner (like PizzaHut) can see all his clients (client who have cards which has points at Pizza Hut)

Technically speaking, I'm trying to write a query to get all clients (ie. a CliProfile queryset) whose cards (at least 1 of all) whose points (at least 1 of all) whose owner (there is only 1) whose user (there is only 1) = request.user ?

Do you have any idea how to write such a query? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear--are you trying to get the `CliProfile` whose `user` = `request.user`? If so, why not just get that and then use that object to query your related objects? i.e. `client = CliProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)`.

Comment: Also along that line, those one to one relationships will create a reverse, so you can just use user.cliprofile

Comment: @Alex I'm not trying to this, it would be easy :) As I tried to explain, it's the clients whose cards (there are several) whose points (there are several) whose bizprofile (there is one) whose user (there is one) == request.user

Comment: @DavidW. What information are you starting with? The `request.user`, right? And what information are you trying to get out of it, the cards related to that user (through the various relations)?

Comment: @Alex : input: request.user (indeed).   output wanted: queryset of CliProfile objects (not exactly the cards as you said, but anyway I need the cards to get the cliprofiles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match fields within models in filter() you need to use two underscores. The following worked for me

```
CliProfile.objects.filter(card__points__at_owner=request.user)
```

But @Alex's suggestion makes the most sense unless this was just an example of what you are trying to do.

If you wanted profiles that are associated with one of several cards you can use the [__in field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
CliProfile.objects.filter(card__in=IterableOfCards)
```

Also you don't use == in [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter). That would return True or False and then pass that value in the filter() call effectively making the call filter(True or False) which won't do anything useful. you have to use = because you are passing a named parameter into the filter function.

Why card instead of card_set()? 
cart_set only exists within an instance of a CliProfile. You are not in an instance of a CliProfile, you are trying to get a list of them.

You can try it in the terminal and it will tell you the valid choices.

```
#Note that it doesn't matter what you put after=, since it fails before that is checked.
>>> CliProfile.objects.filter(card_set=True)
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'card_set' into field. Choices are: card, id, user
```

a CliProfile can be referenced by multiple cards, which is why card_set exists in it but you are trying to match one card. The `card` whose `points` `at_owner` field is `request.user`.

You would use `a_cliprofile_instance.card_set.filter()` to get a subset of their cards or `a_cliprofile_instance.card_set.all()` to display all of their cards

Comment: card_set contains 0->N Card objets. point_set contains 0->N Points object. Are you sure about the syntax in this case? I suppose it would work if card and points were OneToOne RelashionShips, but it's a OneToMany.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer

Comment: card_set only contains 0-> N cards where it exists. It exists only in an instance of a CliProfile. You cant use it to filter CliProfiles since you are not in one when you are making that CliProfile.objects.filter() call

Comment: Thanks for all these explanations! I tried your suggestions. Unfortunately, `CliProfile.objects.filter(card__points__at_owner=request.user)` does not work because it cannot resolve keyword 'card' into field. Could you add the right way to do it with the `in`method for my example? I still don't understand how to do it in my case :( Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what are supposed to be `card` and `points` in your examples: how are they supposed to be resolved since there is no attribute named like this in my models?

Comment: BTW, I updated my question because it was not clear you're right :)

Comment: They are reverse relationships created by django and are created by lowercasing the model name https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships . Just like CliProfile() gets a card_set added to it, filter() gets card and card gets points. If card__ can't be resolved it should tell you what the choices are. What are they?

Comment: Ohh this works like a charm thanks a lot. I had named reverse relashionship, that's why it didn't work at the first time, sorry about that.

Comment: May I ask you something more? Let's imagine that in addition of the clients, I want to get in the same time the `creation_date`attribute of the Points record? This way, for each client, I would know the first time they went to the shop. Thanks...again !

Comment: We are kind of running out of room here, try to figure a new question to ask and post it to SO